# Read External SWF Text

Tags: javascript, php, flash, bots

I'm wanting to start a project that essentially reads the text chat from inside of a Flash game.

I have searched endlessly on Google and read posts that all contained things that needed me to have access to the source code of the flash file (which I don't have access to).

I think it's possible to do, but maybe not in the languages I'd like to do it in (Perl, PHP, and JavaScript). It must be possible to do because there are a lot of chat bots out there in the community, however this is something which I have no experience in and cannot find a solution to.

Pointers to examples, articles, etc. on this matter would be very much appreciated; and if anyone has made something like this before, then please share you expertise on this matter.

Comment: The text is inside the Flash Game. Are you sure it is not stored in a database of some sort. Otherwise you won't be able to extract it, unless you know how to decompile the flash and extract the text.

Comment: I'm positive it's not stored inside a database, because when I refresh the page, all the text is gone and I've seen moderators say "I can't see chat logs". I looked into decompiling and couldn't manage to see how I would install decompiling software on my server so I looked into http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.swf.php however nothing was of use to me there.